# Using isKindOfClass with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, introspection

I'm trying to pick up a bit of Swift lang and I'm wondering how to convert the following Objective-C into Swift:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: UIPickerView.class]) {
      //your touch was in a uipickerview ... do whatever you have to do
    }
}
```

More specifically I need to know how to use `isKindOfClass` in the new syntax.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    ???

    if ??? {
        // your touch was in a uipickerview ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 519, accepted):

The proper Swift operator is `is`:

```
if touch.view is UIPickerView {
    // touch.view is of type UIPickerView
}
```

Of course, if you also need to assign the view to a new constant, then the `if let ... as? ...` syntax is your boy, as Kevin mentioned. But if you don't need the value and only need to check the type, then you should use the `is` operator.

Comment: Works with Swift 3 as well!

Comment: Works with Swift 4.2 as well!

Comment: how can you do this in a switch statement to check several different class types?

Answer (score 134):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    let touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

    if touch.view.isKindOfClass(UIPickerView)
    {

    }
}
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in [@Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift#24020124), the correct way would be to use optional type cast operator `as?`. You can read more about it on the section `Optional Chaining` sub section `Downcasting`.

**Edit 2**

As pointed on the [other answer by user @KPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift#24220444), using the `is` operator is the right way to do it.

Comment: Forgot super in mine. You can also take out the `: UITouch` in this one, as type inference will know what it is by the `as UITouch` cast

Comment: @MalcolmJarvis it doesn't hurt having it.

Comment: Stealing other users' rep by putting their answer in yours is in poor taste.

Comment: doesn't work. Suggests ```UIPickerView.self```. Is it correct?

Answer (score 50):

You can combine the check and cast into one statement:

```
let touch = object.anyObject() as UITouch
if let picker = touch.view as? UIPickerView {
    ...
}
```

Then you can use `picker` within the `if` block.

Comment: This is the "more correct" answer because it uses the Swift 'as?' operator.  The documentation states that "In Objective-C, you use the isKindOfClass: method to check whether an object is of a certain class type, and the conformsToProtocol: method to check whether an object conforms to a specified protocol. In Swift, you accomplish this task by using the is operator to check for a type, or the as? operator to downcast to that type." [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: This is the right way of performing isKingOfClass in swift. You will enter the if block only if the object is of class UIPickerView! Great answer!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that if you just need to do the check and not use 'picker' in the subsequent 'if' block, then you would want to use:    if let _ = touch.view as? UIPickerView { ... }

Comment: @AdamFreeman in that case you'd be better off using `if touch.view is UIPickerView {...}`

Comment: And I'm not sure either `is` or `_` existed at the point this question was asked, a few days after the language was first announced.

Comment: @Kevin I was just trying to let people know about the underscore '_' character and that it can be used for a parameter that is not used in the block you don't have to jump all over my answer

Comment: @Kevin it did exist, as the date of my answer demonstrates ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    let touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

    if let touchView = touch.view as? UIPickerView
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Another approach using the new Swift 2 syntax is to use guard and nest it all in one conditional.

```
guard let touch = object.AnyObject() as? UITouch, let picker = touch.view as? UIPickerView else {
    return //Do Nothing
}
//Do something with picker
```