# AndClass is Kind of class

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to determinate if the AnyClass that is send to my method is Subclass of NSManagedObject

```
    func myFunction (classType:AndClass){

           if classType is NSManagedObject{
              //do some stuff 
           }

    }
```

I guess i'm doing something wrong because the compiler doesn't accept this.

please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift

Comment: if let isClass = classType as? NSManagedObject{
            
        }

Comment: the compiler says that NSManagedObjcet is not a type of AnyObject

Comment: Change `AnyClass` to `AnyObject` that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`AnyClass` is a metatype. Its values are classes, not objects (instances of classes). On the other hand, the values of type `NSManagedObject` are objects. Thus they are not compatible. Your error probably said that "NSManagedObjcet is not a type of AnyObject.Type" (`AnyClass` is an alias for `AnyObject.Type`; the `.Type` signifies a metatype).

You probably wanted `AnyObject` instead of `AnyClass`.

Comment: i had this method in objective-c - (void)myFunction:(Class)classType{ if ([class isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject Class]]){ //do something} } , and i wanted to know how i implement it in swift

Comment: @Janub: Where does `class` come from (there is no such variable declared)? If it is the same as `classType`, then it doesn't make sense, because `[classType isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]` can never be true.