# How to get type of class of delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

How can I know the type of class of a delegate?

`self.delegate.isKindOfClass()` and `self.delegate.isMemberOfClass()` are not working.

When I print 
`println(self.delegate)` It prints the caller controller class. But I cant check it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using isKindOfClass with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check if your delegate is kind of class use the following

```
if self.delegate is ExampleClass {

}
```