# UIView isKindOfClass in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3

So I have this code:

```
if view.isKindOfClass(classType){...}
```

This worked fine in Swift 2, but now that I'm in Swift 3, I get this error:

Value of type `UIView` has no member `isKindOfClass`

How do I test this in Swift 3?

Comment: In Swift you would usually use the `is` operator, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift.

Answer (score 38):

You can try with these three options in **Swift 3**:

Option 1:

```
if view is UITabBarItem {

}
```

Option 2:

```
if view.isKind(of:UITabBarItem.self) {

}
```

Option 3:

```
if view.isMember(of:UITabBarItem.self) {

}
```

The difference between isKind:of and isMember:of is:

- isKind:of returns YES if the receiver is an instance of the exact class, OR if the receiver is an instance of any subclass of the class.
- isMember:of **only** returns YES if the receiver is an instance of the exact class you're checking against

Answer (score 6):

You can use `isKind(of:)` but it's better to use the more swifty `is` and `as`:

See a dumb example:

```
import Foundation

class Base {}
class SuperX: Base {}
class X: SuperX {}
class Y {}

func f(p: Any) {
    print("p: \(p)")
    guard let x = p as? Base
        else { return print("    Unacceptable") }

    if x is X {
        print("    X")
    }
    if x is SuperX {
        print("    Super X")
    }
    else {
        print("    Not X")
    }
}

f(p: Base())
f(p: SuperX())
f(p: X())
f(p: "hey")
f(p: Y())
f(p: 7)
```

Run the code in a playground an the output will be:

```
p: Base
    Not X
p: SuperX
    Super X
p: X
    X
    Super X
p: hey
    Unacceptable
p: Y
    Unacceptable
p: 7
    Unacceptable
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `is` operator for checking like

```
if view is UITableViewCell { 
  //do something
}
```

or

```
guard view is UITableViewCell else {
  return
}
//do something
```

if you need to use the view as instance of class type use `as` operator for casting:

```
if let view = view as? UITableViewCell {
  //here view is a UITableViewCell
}
```

or

```
guard let view = view as? UITableViewCell else {
  return
}
//here view is a UITableViewCell
```