# Swift ios send user to a specific ViewController in tab based application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I want to send a user to a specific ViewController in my app once a notification is clicked.

I now that I can do something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as? HomeViewController
presentedVC?.presentViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But my app has a tab bar and looks like this

Tab bar

tab1: navigationController -> VC1

tab2: navigationController -> VC2 -> HomeVC

tab: navigationController -> VC3

Each tab has a navigationController as a infront of it.

So how can I send the user to HomeVC? I must first select tab 2 then the navigation controller then push the user tvice:

**tab2: navigationController -> VC2 -> HomeVC**

And the other problem, if there any way to tell if the user is already in HomeVC? I dont want to send the user to the same VC if his already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have access to your `UITabbarController` in you `UIApplicationDelegate` or wherever you're handling the notification tap.

```
let tabBar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController //or whatever your way of getting reference is
```

So first you'll get the reference to `UINavigationController` in your second tab like this:

```
let navInTab:UINavigationController = tabBar.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
```

Now push your home view at second tab's navigation controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as? HomeViewController
navInTab.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true)
```

And finally switch your tab to second to show the just pushed home controller

```
tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```

Keep in mind, this answer assumes that your application has already set the tab bar as the root view controller of application window prior handling the notification tap.

Comment: Dont I also need pushViewController() Since the HomeVC is two levels down from the navigation controller?:
**tab2: navigationController -> VC2 -> HomeVC**

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. Yes you indeed need to push view controller instead of `presentViewController()` I've edited my answer.

Comment: But do I need to push it twice since its two levels down?

Comment: yes, check the `topViewController` and `visibleViewController` property of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I am trying ``if(navInTab.topViewController.isKindOfClass(HomeViewController) != nil) {
                        print("is open")
                    } else {
                        print("not open")
                    }``
But I get the error saying UIView has no member isKindOfClass

Comment: Try `navInTab.topViewController is HomeViewControll‌​er` as stated here. [Using isKindOfClass with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24220444/593709)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
  tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 // in your case the second tab
}
```

The idea is to switch to get the tab bar instance and switch it to your desired tab (where you have your view controller).

The above code works in AppDelegate / you can easily call it anywhere by getting the tabBarController instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which tab is selected by user with the method `var selectedIndex: Int`. You can check which `view controller` is present like this `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I did not understand: ``self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController`` can you give me an example on how I use that in order to check if I already are on HomeVC

Comment: presentedViewController is property of UIViewController:
The view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy.