# iOS Swift3 check if a ViewController has been initialized

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Is there a way to check if a ViewController has been initialized in iOS? I have an unwind Segue which does not work i a certain ViewController has not been initialized before.

Comment: if using navigation try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42523549/5461400

Comment: What do you mean by "has been initialized"? Please post the code that's causing you problems. You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried. See [Ask]

Comment: Please post code and let us know your issue ("does not work").

Comment: I perform a Segue, which is an unwind segue. If the destination was never called at runtime, it can not unwind segue to the destination.

For example, i have a StartVC, which decides if the user is already logged in, thus sending the user to the contentVC, or send him to the loginVC. Now if i logout in an app session where the app never called the LoginVC, the app wont perform the unwind segue. That is why i need a way to catch this case and perform a manual segue. Thank you guys for helping!

Comment: _Please_ , show some code!

Comment: The viewControllers are set up in the storyboard, so are the segues, they work if you open that loginVC in runtime, they do not work if loginVC is never accessed. I can not show you any code, i want you to show me code for how to check if my login was created!

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using isKindOf class,

```
if view.isKind(of:UIViewcontroller.self) {
   //do your code while you know the view is initialised.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find root view-controller then used it.

```
if self == UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

or u can used it also

```
if self.window.rootViewController is MyViewController {
//do something if it's an instance of that class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` manages the array(`viewControllers`) of all `UIViewControllers` which are invoked at that instance so do as below

**For swift 3**

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
for aViewController in viewControllers {
if aViewController is YourViewController {

   // get vc here

    break
  }
}
```

**For objective - c**

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

        //Do not forget to import AnOldViewController.h
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {

                   // get vc here
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only works if my view is insie a navigationController. The view i try to check for is a normal viewController.

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher Please clear it either you wanted to check `UIView` or `UIViewController`

Comment: viewcontroller, sorry!

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher If your required `UIViewController` is not in `NavController` that means that vc is not in memory so that `UIViewController` is not initialised at that instant.

Comment: VC is used for UIViewController.