# Not navigate to specific view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to navigate to specific view controller but it is not working.
what i am doing is below

```
    var viewControllers:[UIViewController]!
    var firstView : UIViewController!    

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        firstView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
        viewControllers = [firstView]

@IBAction func BackAction(_ sender: Any) {
        for aViewController in viewControllers {
            if aViewController is FirstViewController {
                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

but not working .
Please help me where i am wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to push or pop to the view controller

Comment: i want to pop to the view controller @Lenin

Comment: Are you sure that FirstViewController is added in navigation Stack

Comment: How to check whether it is added or not ?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826026/how-to-check-viewcontroller-is-added-in-stack-or-not

Comment: if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for vc in viewControllers {
                if vc.isKind(of: FirstViewController.classForCoder()){
                    print("It is in stack")
                    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
                }
            }
        } i have done this but still not working @Lenin

Comment: Is "It is in stack" is print in console

Comment: yes it is printed