# Change tab bar in swift programmatically

Tags: tabs, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to change tab bar in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method programmatically, but it won't work, any idea?

I have tried:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
            }
return true
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that your root view controller is UITabBarController?
because it would seem that you do not enter the if-let.
It's possibile that you've a navigation controller that contains your tab viewcontroller?

Comment: I have a class which HomeTabBarController which inherit from  UITabBarController, I tried with  HomeTabBarController instead of  UITabBarController, but it didn't work

Comment: YES, it doesn't enter.

Comment: check from debug if 'self.window!.rootViewController' is an instance of HomeTabBarController

Comment: ok, you use a navigation controller ? it's possibile that you must check a child of navigation controller (that in your case it would be root viewcontroller)

Comment: in this case you could use this check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826026/how-to-check-viewcontroller-is-added-in-stack-or-not

Comment: Thanks @Alessio, l don't use in my appdelegate navigation controller, so in this case if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers won't work for me, I tried to print  if let viewControllers = window?.rootViewController?.children but some how it shows nil..

Comment: ok, but in debug your rootViewController to which class does it belong?

Comment: Thanks @Alessio, I didn't recognize that my root controller was assign to another view controller, I resolve the issue. thanks