# What is the proper way to use if _ is _ or .isKind(of: )

Tags: ios, swift

I've been struggling to implement this piece of code. I'm converting some legacy code over to swift and I can't get the equivalent of [annotation isKindofClass] to work.

Originally I went with something like (gave me errors

```
mapView.annotations.forEach {
        if !$0.isKind(of: MKUserLocation) {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation($0)
        }
    }
```

But I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019707/using-iskindofclass-with-swift) post that swift had a different way of doing it.

```
mapView.annotations.forEach {
        if !$0 is MKUserLocation {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation($0)
        }
    }
```

this one gives me the error: Cannot convert value of type MKAnnotation to expected argument type BOOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public func isKind(of aClass: AnyClass) -> Bool
```

This function requires `AnyClass` as argument, you must pass a class, using `.self`

```swift
    mapView.annotations.forEach {
        if !$0.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation($0)
        }
    }
```

When use `is`, you must wrap the expression with parentheses:

```swift
    mapView.annotations.forEach {
        if !($0 is MKUserLocation) {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation($0)
        }
    }
```

You are checking boolean value of `$0`, not the `is` expression, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

In short you can do [With](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017530-removeall)

```
mapView.annotations.remove(where:{ !($0 is MKUserLocation) } )
```